# Relation Between Program/Instruction Pointer(RIP) and Base/Frame Pointer(RBP) on 64 bit Linux

Tags: ptrace

i need some help on retrieving Instruction pointers(**RIP**) of a call stack on Linux **64 bit** machine. i can traverse the Stack using ptrace and retrieve all Frame/Base pointer(**RBP**) values. but as i want IP values, what is the arithmetic and conceptual relationship between RIP and RBP. **i assume that RIP value is stored at (RBP + 8) location and a can read it using ptrace PEEKDATA**. is my assumption correct?

Comment: The layout of the call stack depends on the calling convention and processor architecture. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention. Maybe ptrace abstracts this away but I don't actually know.

Answer (score 2):

Any return address pushed on the stack will only get you the `%rip` starting after the currently running function returns, not the `%rip` of the currently executing function. You should be able to get your hands on the current `%rip` the same way GDB does:

- Ideally, your platform supports the `PTRACE_GETREGS` or `PTRACE_GETREGSET` argument. Your manpage and the header file should get you the rest of the way from here.
- Failing that, you should be able to use the `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` argument with the appropriate offset to grab the register from the user area.

You can look at the gorey details in `gdb/amd64-linux-nat.c` in the GDB source tree.